# Arrangement-of-rectangles algorithm and investigating it on a per-coordinate basis

Tags: java, algorithm, math

(I am not sure if this qualifies as CodeGolf, as I do actually have a use for this despite its abstract-sounding nature... xD If it does, let me know and I'll add it to the tags...)

This problem consists out of two joined-at-the-hip parts: one about finding a suitable formula/algorithm, and the other about using that algorithm to deal with the basic needs that I am eventually interested in.

Suppose you have a sufficiently large two-dimensional field that needs to be filled with rectangles. Pre-generating the locations of these non-overlapping rectangles (of various sizes, which are subject to a minimum and maximum size) is unfeasible due to memory constraints. These rectangles themselves are not subject to the 'grid' implied by the field; a random rectangle can be rotated to any degree: 30, 45 or 87 or whatever degree angle, it is fine as long as it does not overlap with any other rectangles. The 'density' of the rectangles would be rather low, thus leaving a lot of empty space between them. (If the algorithm could be easily tweaked for as far this density is concerned, that would be very interesting!) Generating the positions of the rectangles are the result of a single input 64-bit 'seed', of which varying inputs should lead to different results in the arranged layout of rectangles. Finally, the output should not be overly grid-like or recognizably regular; visually speaking, it should be a pretty chaotic arrangement if plotted.

```
// Note: This algorithm would not actually generate or produce to start
// off with. The logic is concentrated in the questions that follow below.
// Please note: there is NO initialization phase of any sort.
```

Visual aid: [image]

Now, given **only** the knowledge of a certain (x, y) coordinate and the generating 'seed', how can I determine whether this coordinate is inside of a rectangle? How do I determine the corners of said rectangle? And finally, how do I get the center coordinate of the nearest Rectangle?

```
public Boolean isInsideRectangle(int x, int y, long seed) { ... }

public Boolean isCornerOfRectangle(int x, int y, long seed) { ... }

public Point getCenterOfNearestRectangle(int x, int y, long seed) { ... }
```

I simply have no clue how to approach this problem, or I would include some code. The world of math is one I am not well-versed in. So while I most definitely welcome code, explanations are even more welcome. :-)

(Pre-emptive 'No, it is not homework or anything of the sort.' needs to be included: this is just one facet of a personal project.)

Comment: A naive approach that comes to mind is to seed a pseudo random generator with your seed and pick doubles in packs of 5 (x and y, rotation, length and width), discard in the case of overlap. That will get you reproducible, random rectangles. Store them in memory and you can iterate through for your three functions. This is all very inefficient, but might provide a starting point.

Comment: Sadly, that breaks the 'no memory' limitation. Generating rectangles each call does not guarantee the calculated rectangle is anywhere near the given point, and calculating all rectangles during each call is madness as well runtime-wise. I did figure I could use separate bit-groups for stuff like rotation, length and width, and maybe use an irregular-spread-of-points algorithm for the center of the rectangles, but the obvious (naive) implementation of that would lead the `getCenterOfNearestRectangle()` function to produce incorrect results. Thanks for your insights though!

Comment: Have you made any progress?

Comment: Yeah, I in fact managed to make some progress thanks to your comment. I decided to stop overthinking it, and fed a RNG the seed plus some other 'reproducible' data multiplied with some randomly chosen huge primes, and have just been sucking that dry to get information that is relatively random in nature. If I manipulate the 'random' factors, I can most definitely minimize the amount of rectangles and thus collisions, although they do happen. Not pretty but kind of liveable for now. I recalculate all rectangle centerpoints in some MIN_RECT_RANGE when needed, and so far performance is okayish.